# Overlapping image within DIV

Tags: css, xhtml

I have some divs which contain an image that fills the whole div:

```
<div class="callout">
    <img src="images/callout_image.gif" alt=""/>
</div>

.callout { float: left; width: 267px; height: 114px; }
```

Now I want to put another image in this DIV which overlaps part of the original image AND will also "pop out" of the DIV, i.e. it will extend beyond the dimensions of the DIV but the DIV itself does not extend.

I am having trouble doing this, can anyone help?

Comment: you can increase the width of callout div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<div class="callout">
    <img src="images/callout_image.gif" alt=""/>
    <img src="images/callout_image.gif" alt="" class="pop" />
</div>

.callout { float: left; width: 267px; height: 114px; position: relative;}
.pop {position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; z-index: 1;}
```

You might need to set `overflow: visible` on the `div` depending on the circumstances.